# Add a simple key-value pair to existing JSON using jq

Tags: jq

I am totally new to jq so sorry for the simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer to this.  How do I simply concatenate a new JSON key/value pair to some existing JSON.  For example, say I have:

```
{"key1": "value1"}
```

in variable A in a bash script.  I now want to add:

```
{"key2": "value2"}
```

to A using jq so that that the resulting contents of A are:

```
{"key1": "value1",
 "key2": "value2"}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: It would look virtually the same with `jq`: `A=$(<<<$A jq '. + {key2: "value2"})`.

Comment: The above jq command doesn't work.  It simply results in a ">" prompt.

Comment: GregH - chepner's answer is fine except for the obviously-missing single-quotation mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a bash prompt:

```
A='{"key1": "value1"}'
$ echo $A
{"key1": "value1"}
A=$(jq -n --argjson A "$A" '$A + {"key2": "value2"}')
$ echo $A
{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }
$
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  When executed and I echo $A, I get the result:   }key2": "value2",

Comment: I updated the answer to clarify that the prompt is a bash prompt.